# How to back up Fedora Linux and restore or load image in VMWare

Tags: linux, debian, backup, system, fedora

Good afternoon,

I have a task of backing up an entire drive ~20gB of a Fedora Installation (don't know the exact release). I would prefer to back this up into an image on an External Hard drive, so if the system fails, I will be able to easily restore it onto an identical drive. The drive the system is on is not a hard drive, it is I believe a CF Card. But it may actually be a small hard drive.

So, to my understanding, in order to restore it, I would need to use another linux computer to flash the CF card using the image.

I have no previous experience backing up files in Linux, so in order for me to use any of your help, I would like to request that the answers have the exact commands I will need to do this backup and restore.

It is also imperative that the original installation remains intact and does not get damaged by this backup process.

Thank you,
Your help is appreciated,
-D

Comment: A Debian-based Fedora? I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync is a good backup tool, but if you want a *complete dump of everything* that can only be restored to the same drive, look at the good old dd. It can dump the whole drive to a file that you can later use to restore.

Comment: Thanks, any chance I can get the actual commands I need to type in? Including the excludes, so I don't get an infinite loop. I'm new to linux and I cannot make a mistake backing up this drive. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To create a backup that you could use for bare metal restore, I'd recommend using a Live CD to create a complete backup or an image.

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) and [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/Main_Page) are free applications that come to mind, Acronis (commercial) is also quite good.